# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de una fila de un DataTable al seleccionarlo con jquery para guardar el valor en un textbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

Tengo mi tabla con la información, pero necesito seleccionar una fila y guardar información en un `textbox` alguna guía de como hacerlo.

```html
<!-- Modal Escenario-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="popupBusquedaCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Busqueda de Categorias</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="BusquedaCliente" class="modal-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="stock_bodega">Busqueda por:</label>
                                <select class="form-control" style="width: 40%" id="stock_bodega">
                                    <option>C&oacute;digo</option>
                                    <option>Nombre</option>
                                    <option>Estado</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="texto_buscar">Texto a Buscar:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="texto_buscar">
                            </div>

                            <div style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="dataTables_scrollBody">
                                <table style="width: 100%;" id="busqueda_cliente" class="display nowrap dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Codigo</th>
                                            <th>Nombre</th>
                                            <th>Estado</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    @* Load datatable css *@
                    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                    @* Load datatable js *@
                    @section Scripts{
                        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $('#busqueda_cliente').DataTable({
                                    "bSort": false,
                                    "ajax": {
                                        "url": "/venmancategoria/Todos",
                                        "type": "GET",
                                        "datatype": "json"
                                    },
                                    "columns": [
                                            { "data": "Codigo" },
                                            { "data": "Nombre" },
                                            { "data": "Estado" }
                                    ],
                                    filter: false,
                                    "paging":   false,
                                    "ordering": false,
                                    "info":     false,
                                    language: {
                                        paginate: {
                                            first: "Primero",
                                            previous: "Anterior",
                                            next: "Siguiente",
                                            last: "Ultimo"
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    }
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Seleccionar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  <!-- Modal Escenario-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre esta solución, espero sea lo que necesitas, saludos.

```js
$("#tabla").on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var renglon = $(this);
  var campo1, campo2, campo3;
  $(this).children("td").each(function(i) {
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        campo1 = $(this).text();
        break;
      case 1:
        campo2 = $(this).text();
        break;
    }
    $(this).css("background-color", "#ECF8E0");
  })
  var textoRenglon = campo1 + ' - ' + campo2
  //console.log(textoRenglon);
  $("#text").val(textoRenglon);
  //alert(renglon);
});

$("#tabla2").on('click', 'td', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var campo = $(this).text();
  //Cambiando de color la celda
  $(this).css("background-color", "#ECF8E0");
  //console.log(campo);
  $("#text2").val(campo);
  //alert(renglon);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Pasar todo el row a un text </h1>
<table border="1" id="tabla">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Juan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Pedro</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="text" type="text" value='' />

<br/>

<h1>Pasar solo la celda seleccionada </h1>
<table border="1" id="tabla2">
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Maria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Juana</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="text2" type="text" value='' />


<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: En si me funciona pero solo me obtine el valor de la primera columna sera que falta algo mas.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código con que estas pasando la fila al textbox?

Comment: $("#txt_codigo").val(campo1);
$("txt_nombre").val(campo2); 
$("txt_codigoCat").val(campo3);
$("#txt_categoria_detalle").val(campo4); solo agregue mas opciones al case y comente esta linea de tu codigo var textoRenglon = campo1 + ' - ' + campo2

Comment: Mira, te falta:

 $("#txt_nombre").val(campo2); $("#txt_codigoCat").val(campo3);  // Agregarle el signo de #

Comment: En jQuery cuando llamas a un objeto por id se pone el signo # <--  Ejemplo: $("#idDelObjeto")   y cuando lo llamas por clase se pone el . <-- Ejmplo: $(".claseDeLosObjetos"), el id es único y las clase pueden estar en muchos objetos.  Espero que con eso lo puedas solucionar.

Comment: si me funciono bien muchas gracias Cristina

Comment: Excelente, si tienes alguna otra duda con gusto te ayudo.  :-)